# Can't roll back cryptography; was not uninstalled | During sudo pip install mitmproxy

Tags: python, pip, raspberry-pi, cryptography, mitmproxy

I'm trying to run the following command: `sudo pip install mitmproxy` on my Raspberry Pi 3.

Running the command, I have run into a couple of problems with different things failing due to certain libraries missing, and those were simple fixes. This one in particular, I cannot seem to be able to fix it:

`Can't roll back cryptography; was not uninstalled Command "/usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-3ZDe_T/cryptography/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-record-wmW08I/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-3ZDe_T/cryptography/`

I have tried the following commands:
`sudo apt-get install libffi-dev`
`sudo apt-get install python-pip python-dev libffi-dev libssl-dev libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev libjpeg8-dev zlib1g-dev`
`sudo apt-get install build-essential libssl-dev libffi-dev python-dev`
All pretty much doing the same thing, but in different ways.

I'm not really sure what to do. Here is the [full log](https://pastebin.com/TnFFfrPL).

Thanks!

Comment: If I interpret the log correctly you are still using python2 which is deprecated and should not be used anymore. I strongly recommend to you to only use python3.

Comment: Which makes complete sense; I actually fixed this the other day installing it with Python 3, a mistake on my part. Thanks!
This command `sudo pip3 install mitmproxy`